# What causes the oscillation that generates the waves in an electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm reading "The Feynman Lectures" regarding electromagnetism. I'm having a problem understanding what exactly disturbs the electromagnetic field and generates the waves.
I assuming the field is usually in equilibrium and adding protons would create a potential for the electrons to move towards them.
But how do you actually add them, where do they come from?
Also, in order to have a wave, something must be oscillating. What's oscillating in this case?

Sorry for the very beginner question, I just want to fully understand the process before moving on.

Comment: have a look here  http://homepage.physics.uiowa.edu/~rmerlino/6Fall10/29006_L30.pdf.  Changing electric fields generate electromagnetic waves , in antennas. The electrons move up and down the metal of the antenna , and the antenna radiates.

Comment: @annav Isn’t this slightly different than what the OP is asking? Oscillating electrons up and down an antenna does create oscillating waves of photons but the OP is asking about the wave itself. In other words you could send electrons up an antenna one time only and still create a wave of photons radiating outward. That one wave of photons still has an oscillation and that’s what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @BillAlsept photons do not oscilate. They have fixed energy hν , mass zero, spin 1. It is the confluence of photons that shows the classical electromagnetic wave oscillations : see https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html . my previous commnt is in classical electrodynamics.

Comment: @annav that still does not answer where the oscillation is coming from. Accelerating electrons will create waves of photons but does not explain why the wave has an oscillation. How in the world can hv be fixed considering it’s in equation of multiplication and frequency. Billions of photons oscillating as they propagate outward from a common source can explain every phenomenon we see in light. See figure 12 on page 7 of “Single Edge Certainty” at billalsept.com

Answer (score 1):

> I assuming the [electric] field is usually in equilibrium and adding protons would create a potential for the electrons to move towards them. But how do you actually add them, where do they come from?

At the beginning of electricity observations and use were some **inventions**:

- a lot of different working [electrostatic generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_generator) to separate electric charges
- the [Leiden jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyden_jar) to store separated electric charges
- [Voltaic respectively Galvanic cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell) and [Batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(electricity)#History), which are electrochemical cells that derives electrical energy from spontaneous redox reactions taking place within the cell.

[image: Electrostatic generator] [image: Galvanic cell]

In all that cases the electrons are the easier to move charges and they are the one which flow through the wires during separation or during the process of re-equilibration.

The best adoptable invention to our modern live was the [electric dynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo#Etymology), in our days called [electric power generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo#Electric_power_generation), and the [electric motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motor). Both devices based on the discovered phenomenon of the **[electromagnetic induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction#Theory)**.

> > Generating an EMF through a variation of the magnetic flux through the surface of a wire loop can be achieved in several ways:
> >
> > - the magnetic field B changes (e.g. an alternating magnetic field,
> > - or moving a wire loop towards a bar magnet where the B field is stronger),
> > - the wire loop is deformed and the surface Σ changes,
> > - the orientation of the surface dA changes (e.g. spinning a wire loop into a fixed magnetic field),
> > - any combination of the above. (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction#Theory))

To your next question:

> Also, in order to have a wave, something must be oscillating. What's oscillating in this case?

There are alternating currents and direct currents. In the last nothing is oscillations, simply the electrons from a DC generator or a battery are flowing from the source to the sink. In alternating currents a generator converts the rotation of a shaft with coils and an applied magnetic field (or vice versa) into an oscillating potential and the electrons in the wire get pushed forth and back.

Any acceleration of charges is accompanied by **electromagnetic radiation**, the electrons emit photons. This is a non suppresable process. Whenever electrons are running inside a coil and even if a body is accelerated, the electrons radiate.

This phenomenon of EM radiation was adopted to send informations around the globe. **Radio waves** are made in a radiating antenna rod by the help of an electric generator which pushes the electrons inside the rod forth and back. A receiver gets tuned to the same frequency as the sender and the sender modulated on the carrier frequency the informations which the receiver transformed back to music or a data stream.

> I'm having a problem understanding what exactly disturbs the electromagnetic field and generates the waves.

Quantum mechanics was developed to describe processes inside the atoms:

> > Quantum mechanics ... is a fundamental theory in physics which describes nature at the smallest scales of energy levels of atoms and subatomic particles. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics)

Apart from the introduction of these QM theories about an overall existing EM field in practice **one could measure**

- local acting electric fields (from the separation of electric field),
- local acting magnetic fields (from permanent magnets or from accelerated in circles  charges),
- electromagnetic radiation from the emission of photons and as a special case
- EM waves (radio waves) as modulated EM radiation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to add charges to a system in order to generate electromagnetic waves.  EM waves are caused by the *acceleration* of charges, typically of charges that are already in the system.  There are many, many ways to accelerate charges.  A simple way is to produce an alternating current in a wire loop by, for example, spinning it rapidly in a stationary magnetic field on an axis that is in the plane of the loop and perpendicular to the direction of the magnetic field.

An EM wave does not need to oscillate in the ordinary sense of the word "oscillate". An electromagnetic pulse could be caused, for example, by sudden and brief acceleration of a charge to a high velocity (so that the acceleration occurs in just one direction). However, the pulse can be decomposed into (oscillating) wave forms covering a continuous range of frequencies. Running the pulse through a prism or diffraction grating will separate the frequency components. Neither pulse nor components are caused initially by oscillating charge, only by that briefly accelerated charge.

Comment: There is still a difference between what the OP is asking and what you’re saying. For sure EM waves are caused by accelerated charges. An alternating current (which is an oscillation) creates waves each time it oscillates. This does not explain the Isolation of an individual EM wave. For example if you accelerate a charged particle one time without an alternating current, you still get an EM wave which oscillates. That is a different oscillation than the manipulation of the charged particles.

Comment: What do you mean by "accelerate a charged particle one time without an alternating current, you still get an EM wave which oscillates"?  Please give a specific example.

Comment: your first three sentences I totally agree with. EM waves are emitted from accelerating charged particles and there are many ways to accelerate them. Your fourth sentence introduces alternating current as if that’s has something to do with the oscillations the OP was talking about. An alternating current accelerates electrons back and forth multiple times instead of just one acceleration. That is a totally different type of oscillation than the oscillation in an EM wave.

Comment: In that case I think you may have an unusual way to define an EM wave. I gave alternating current as one example of a way to generate accelerating charges that produce an EM wave.  It seems that you are saying that alternating current does *not* produce an EM wave.  Please clarify.

Comment: no I am not saying that at all. Of course an  alternating current emits photons and produces an EM wave. I am saying discussing alternating currents confuses the subject of oscillations. The OP was asking about the oscillation of EM waves and not the oscillation of electrical currents.

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify the fact that an EM pulse can be generated without charge oscillation.